# The raster overlay function in R produces incorrect values for raster bricks

Tags: r, overlay, raster

I'm trying to quantile match two RasterBricks. I am finding the percentile of value<=250 in `old_data`, which we'll call **p**. Then I'm finding the value at the **p**^th quantile of each cell in `new_data`. The overlay function seems to be giving me really weird results.

So first I find the percentiles of 250 in each cell of the RasterBrick `old_data`:

```
percentiles <- old_data %>% 
  stackApply(indices = 1, fun = function(x, ...) {sum(x<=250)/length(x)})
summary(percentiles)

>           index_1
> Min.    0.6702177
> 1st Qu. 0.7919252
> Median  0.9108949
> 3rd Qu. 0.9661281
> Max.    0.9950102
> NAs     0.0000000

plot(percentiles)
```

[image: percentiles]

This is all well and good, matches what I would expect. I am expecting the quantile-matched values in `new_data` to be around or below 250, and a few spot checks at random cells confirms that assumption:

```
x <- c(raster::extract(new_data, 1))
y <- raster::extract(percentiles, 1)
sort(x)[y*length(x)]
> [1] 245.0346

x <- c(raster::extract(new_data, 10))
y <- raster::extract(percentiles, 10)
sort(x)[y*length(x)]
> [1] 203.5514

x <- c(raster::extract(new_data, 50))
y <- raster::extract(percentiles, 50)
sort(x)[y*length(x)]
> [1] 224.4567

x <- c(raster::extract(new_data, 100))
y <- raster::extract(percentiles, 100)
sort(x)[y*length(x)]
> [1] 209.7806
```

But then when I use the overlay function to get quantiles across the whol extent of the raster, I'm getting numbers that are way wrong.

```
new_quantiles <- overlay(
  x = new_data, y = percentiles, 
  fun = function(x, y) {sort(x)[y*length(x)]})
summary(new_quantiles)

>            layer
> Min.    145.1617
> 1st Qu. 191.8718
> Median  281.7506
> 3rd Qu. 398.2013
> Max.    640.2073
> NAs       0.0000

plot(new_quantiles)
```

[image: new quantiles]

I don't understand. I should definitely not be getting values that high. I'm using the exact same formula, and the raster bricks are on identical grids so there's no issue with origin or resolution. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without some example data. For example (here using {terra}, the replacement of {raster}; but it would be mostly the same for {raster})

```
library(terra)
old <- rast(nl=10)
values(old) <- sample(500, size(old), replace=TRUE)
new <- rast(nl=5)
values(new) <- sample(500, size(new), replace=TRUE)
```

Your approach to compute the percentiles seems overly complex, as you can do:

```
p <- mean(old <= 250)
summary(p)
```

(It makes no sense to use `stackApply` (`tapp` in terra) with a single index for all layers; instead you can either use a direct arithmetic approach as above, or use `calc` (`app` in terra))

I do not understand what you are trying to achieve with overlay (what you mean with "get values everywhere"). Perhaps you can edit your question to make the code simpler and reproducible.

Without a reproducible example, all I can say is that the use of `length` in the function supplied to `overlay` is suspect. It may not be the length you expect.

Comment: Point taken about stackApply, and I removed the phrase "get values everywhere." I was referring to the difference between performing the calculation at individual locations vs. performing the calculation on the whole raster. But what I'm really stuck on is the overlay() function, and why performing the exact same function -- function(x,y) sort(x)[y*length(x)] -- produces different values if I use overlay() vs. if I loop individually over all cells.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible?